# Java short lived objects & garbage collection

Tags: java, android, performance, garbage-collection

I am evaluating the performance impact of creating small short lived objects frequently (say every second) on garbage collection and memory footprint, especially on Android java implementation.

To elaborate further, we have an application which receives frequent update from the network in thread and it is passed to application in a small structure. In C, we create a local variable of type structure and pass it like

```
void passToApp(int a, int b, int c) {

   AppStruct p;
   p.a = a;
   p.b = b;
   p.c = c;
   appFunction(&p);
}
```

This is not a problem in C as p is in stack. However in java, every object need to be allocated and later to be freed by GC.

```
void passToApp(int a, int b, int c) {

   AppStruct p = new AppStruct();
   p.a = a;
   p.b = b;
   p.c = c;
   appFunction(p);
}
```

Please share your insight on the situation and any best practices in such circumstances.

Comment: [Profile it and see if there is any issue](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil). The impact will be 0 when it happens only once per second.

Comment: if you're trying to optimize things like this, you're probably using the wrong platform... that aside, Java is generally very quick in allocation, and if they're short live they will never leave Eden space, which is also very efficient.  Best way is to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make all objects like this

```
    private class AppStruct{
        boolean used;

        public void release() {
            used = false;
        }
    };
    private final static int MAX_COUNT = 100;
    private final AppStruct[] pool = new AppStruct[MAX_COUNT];
    public AppStruct obtain() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pool.length; ++i){
            if (!pool[i].used) {
                pool[i].used = true;
                return pool[i];
            }
        }
        // max count is set wrong
        return new AppStruct();
    }
```

This is just simple example, you should maybe make list or something.

Main idea is to make `final` object, which will be created only one time and this will be ok with GC. It's better not to create many objects, because it can lag UI thread and slow down FPS